# How to add values of common elements in list of lists and make it as one using python?

Tags: python, list

i really need your help to solve my homework. How can i add both list with same element in python?

Example:

```py
list = [[5, 'jay'], [20, 'jenny'], [10, 'john'], [13, 'jay'], [10,'jenny']]
```

Output should be like this:

```py
list = [[18, 'jay'], [30, 'jenny'], [10, 'john']]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Build up the target list in a loop (but don't call it `list` since that name has a built-in meaning in Python).

Answer (score -1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

input = [[5, 'jay'], [20, 'jenny'], [10, 'john'], [13, 'jay'], [10,'jenny']]
temp = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for pair in input:
  temp[pair[1]] += pair[0]
output = list(map(lambda x: [x[1], x[0]], temp.items()))

print(output)
```

Comment: This is someone's homework. They haven't shown any work. And you just posted a solution for it. And you've used advanced python techniques that are likely foreign to a beginner - imagine them turning in your solution as their homework and getting questioned to explain it. Even if the original question *was* on topic, you posted code with no explanations. Please don't do this, as it's not how this site works. The question should be marked as off-topic.